# Passing a Scriptblock with complex Arguments to a New Powershell Instance

Tags: powershell, arguments, start-process

I want to execute the following script with complex arguments. For example with [securestring].

```
$text = "'This is a test message.'"

$ArgumentList = @( $text, $PID ) -join ", "
$cmd = { param([string]$msg, [int]$proc ); Write-Host "$msg FROM PID: $proc" }
$Command = "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$cmd} -ArgumentList $ArgumentList"

Start-Process -Filepath powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command ( $Command )"
```

this script worked fine.
i`m transform this script into the new one

```
$text = "'This is a test message.'"
$Cred = get-credential
$ArgumentList = @( $text, $PID, $credential ) -join ", "
$cmd = { param([string]$msg, [int]$proc, $Credential ); Write-Host "$msg FROM PID: $proc, cred: $( $Credential.username )" }
$Command = "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$cmd} -ArgumentList $ArgumentList"

Start-Process -Filepath powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command ( $Command )"
```

I have an error.
How to pass arguments right?

Comment: Is it important to have the credential object available _inside_ the new process context? `Start-Process -Credential $cred` not sufficient?

Comment: I`m talking not about Credential parameter. Credential is nested scriptblock argument.

Comment: The credential object can't be "stringified", hence the error you receive. Please answer my question

Comment: You are right, i dont want to "stringify" credential. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [**@Mathias**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), I would consider to run the whole process under the specific credentials

```
Start-Process -Credential $cred -Filepath powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command ( $Command )"
```

Anyways, you might also [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (all) your arguments and convert it to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) as you passing it trough multiple interpreters:

```
$text = "This is a test message."
$Cred = get-credential
$Arguments = @{
    Msg  = $Text
    Proc = $PID
    Cred = $Cred
}
$Serialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($Arguments)
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Serialized)
$Base64 =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$cmd = {
    param([String]$Base64)
    $Serialized = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($Base64))
    $Arguments = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($Serialized)
    Write-Host " $($Arguments.msg) FROM PID: $($Arguments.proc), cred: $( $Arguments.Cred.Username)"
}
$Command = "Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$cmd} -ArgumentList $Base64"

Start-Process -Filepath powershell -ArgumentList "-noexit -command ( $Command )"
```

**Note:** that [`Get-Credential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-credential) by default uses the Windows data protection API, and the key used to encrypt the password is specific to both the user and the machine that the code is running under.

Comment: Thanks, Mathias! You read my mind, i`am also going this direction.