# PowerShell: Is there a better way to handle passing arrays to another script than what I'm doing?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters

I'm writing a PowerShell script to create a Windows cluster at AWS.  I need to run a script which first retries the domain admin credentials and then passes params to the next script.  Involved are 2 arrays with node name and IP addresses.  The original working example from AWS is as follows (note the way they have the array values wrapped in double quotes):

```
# Populate the cluster node names and set the cluster name for the WSFC
$WSFCClusterName = "WSFC1"
$ClusterNodes = ("SQLNode1", "SQLNode2")
$ClusterIPs = ("172.31.10.101", "172.31.20.101")

# Create a Cluster
New-Cluster -Name $WSFCClusterName -Node $ClusterNodes -AdministrativeAccessPoint ActiveDirectoryAndDNS -StaticAddress $ClusterIPs

# Rename Cluster Resources
$ClusterIPResources = Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "IP Address"} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$ClusterIPResources.ForEach( { (Get-ClusterResource -Name "$_").Name = Get-ClusterResource -Name "$_" | Get-ClusterParameter -Name Address | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value } )
(Get-ClusterGroup "Cluster Group").Name = $WSFCClusterName
(Get-ClusterResource | Where-Object {$_.ResourceType -eq "Network Name" -and $_.OwnerGroup -eq $WSFCClusterName}).Name = $WSFCClusterName

# Set possible owners for IP addresses - each node can only own its own IP
for($i = 0; $i -le 1; $i++){ Get-Cluster -Name $WSFCClusterName | Get-ClusterResource -Name $ClusterIPs[$i] | Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Owners $ClusterNodes[$i] }

# Set dependencies for the cluster name object to be either/or for the node IP addresses
Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource $WSFCClusterName -Dependency ("[$($ClusterIPs[0])] or [$($ClusterIPs[1])]")

# Test the cluster
Test-Cluster
```

In my first script, I have the following:

**New-Cluster-Credential.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$WSFCClusterName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string[]]$ClusterNodes,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string[]]$ClusterIPs
)

Write-Host "`nRetrieving domain credentials..."
. C:\SETUP\common_scripts\getADCredentials.ps1

$ClusterNodes = [string]::Join(",",$ClusterNodes)
$ClusterIPs = [string]::Join(",",$ClusterIPs)

$Arguments = ".\New-Cluster.ps1 -WSFCClusterName $WSFCClusterName -ClusterNodes $ClusterNodes -ClusterIPs $ClusterIPs"

Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList "-NoExit -c cd '$pwd'; & $Arguments"
```

At the prompt I run it like so:

```
.\New-Cluster-Credential.ps1 -WSFCClusterName "CLTEST10" -ClusterNodes ("CLTEST10-01", "CLTEST10-02") -ClusterIPs ("10.0.123.100", "10.0.223.100")
```

In the next script that launches with domain credentials:

**New-Cluster.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$WSFCClusterName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string[]]$ClusterNodes,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string[]]$ClusterIPs
)

$Parameters = @{
    Name          = $WSFCClusterName
    Node          = $ClusterNodes
    StaticAddress = $ClusterIPs
    NoStorage     = $true
    AdministrativeAccessPoint = 'ActiveDirectoryAndDNS'
}

# Create Cluster
Write-Host "`nCreating New Cluster: $WSFCClusterName"
New-Cluster @Parameters
```

That all works fine, but when it gets to the part of the original working script, its getting choked up on the array references $ClusterIPs[$i] $ClusterNodes[$i] [$($ClusterIPs[0])] [$($ClusterIPs[1])]

```
#Set possible owners for IP addresses - each node can only own its own IP
for($i = 0; $i -le 1; $i++){ Get-Cluster -Name $WSFCClusterName | Get-ClusterResource -Name $ClusterIPs[$i] | Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Owners $ClusterNodes[$i] }

#Set dependencies for the cluster name object to be either/or for the node IP addresses
Set-ClusterResourceDependency -Resource $WSFCClusterName -Dependency ("[$($ClusterIPs[0])] or [$($ClusterIPs[1])]")
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might consider to [serialize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) (all) your arguments and convert it to [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) as you passing it trough multiple interpreters, see also: [Passing a Scriptblock with complex Arguments to a New Powershell Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72868944/1701026).

Comment: If you want arrays you are missing the `@` : `@("CLTEST10-01", "CLTEST10-02")`

Comment: @jdweng No, PowerShell assumes arrays whenever it sees items combine with a comma, so `$stuff = "CLTEST10-01", "CLTEST10-02"` will be an array. Wrapping it inside `@()` won't hurt, but is not necessary. You use `@()` only to make absolutely sure that whatever is in `$stuff` will be or become an array, so you can use the `.Count` property, iterate etc.

Answer (score 0):

I used a function to test your parameters.  Had to add Alias.

```
Function TestParams
{
   param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Alias("Resource")]
    [string]$WSFCClusterName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Alias("Nodes")]
    [string[]]$ClusterNodes,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [Alias("Dependency")]
    [string[]]$ClusterIPs

   ) 
   Write-Host $WSFCClusterName 
   Write-Host $ClusterNodes
   Write-Host $ClusterIPs 
}


$WSFCClusterName = "WSFC1"
$ClusterNodes = @("SQLNode1", "SQLNode2")
$ClusterIPs = @("172.31.10.101", "172.31.20.101")
TestParams -Resource $WSFCClusterName -Nodes $ClusterNodes -Dependency $ClusterIPs
```